# Django CMS Aldryn Create Wizard database error

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm using Aldryn Newsblog and FAQ plugins. Django version 1.8.8,  Django CMS 3.2.0.

I'm trying to create a new blog article or FAQ question by pressing "Create" in the toolbar (image 1).

[image: What I'm clicking and what's broken]

It pops up a nice wizard for filling in the content, but when I actually submit it I get the error in image 2:

"DatabaseError at /cms_wizard/create/
Save with update_fields did not affect any rows.".

[image: The error]

Stack trace:

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:9000/cms_wizard/create/

Django Version: 1.8.8
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('djangocms_admin_style',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'cms',
 'menus',
 'sekizai',
 'treebeard',
 'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
 'djangocms_ckeditor_filer',
 'filer',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'wwb',
 'adminsortable2',
 'aldryn_apphooks_config',
 'aldryn_boilerplates',
 'aldryn_categories',
 'aldryn_common',
 'aldryn_newsblog',
 'aldryn_faq',
 'aldryn_people',
 'aldryn_reversion',
 'aldryn_translation_tools',
 'parler',
 'reversion',
 'sortedm2m',
 'taggit',
 'gunicorn')
Installed Middleware:
('cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
 'djangocms_ckeditor_filer.middleware.ThumbnailMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cms/wizards/views.py" in dispatch
  38.             request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  237.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in post
  300.                 return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in render_done
  357.                                   **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cms/wizards/views.py" in done
  148.         instance = form_two.save()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/aldryn_newsblog/cms_wizards.py" in save
  112.                     body=content,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cms/api.py" in add_plugin
  347.     plugin.save()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/djangocms_text_ckeditor/models.py" in save
  47.         super(AbstractText, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pluginmodel.py" in save
  248.         super(CMSPlugin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  734.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  762.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  831.                 raise DatabaseError("Save with update_fields did not affect any rows.")

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /cms_wizard/create/
Exception Value: Save with update_fields did not affect any rows.
```

Settings.py file:

```
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
DATA_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'g67=r(8b)#=!x1^ddido=qp&9_pq=5&acs%u=xr_xe7t3uq70n'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition


ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Dublin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'media/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp', 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp', 'templates'),
)
SITE_ID = 1

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wwb', 'templates'),
    ],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'debug': True,
        'context_processors':
        [
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.core.context_processors.debug',
            'django.core.context_processors.request',
            'django.core.context_processors.media',
            'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
            'django.core.context_processors.tz',
            'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
            'django.core.context_processors.static',
            'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
            'aldryn_boilerplates.context_processors.boilerplate',
        ],
        'loaders':
        [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
            'aldryn_boilerplates.template_loaders.AppDirectoriesLoader',
        ]
    }
},
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
    'djangocms_ckeditor_filer.middleware.ThumbnailMiddleware'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',

    #for uploading images to ckeditor
    'djangocms_ckeditor_filer',

    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'wwb',

    #for aldryn-blog and aldryn-faq
    'adminsortable2',
    'aldryn_apphooks_config',
    'aldryn_boilerplates',
    'aldryn_categories',
    'aldryn_common',
    'aldryn_newsblog',
    'aldryn_faq',
    'aldryn_people',
    'aldryn_reversion',
    'aldryn_translation_tools',
    'parler',
    'reversion',
    'sortedm2m',
    'taggit',

    'gunicorn',

)

ALDRYN_BOILERPLATE_NAME = 'bootstrap3'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'aldryn_boilerplates.staticfile_finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

THUMBNAIL_HIGH_RESOLUTION = True

THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.scale_and_crop',
    'filer.thumbnail_processors.scale_and_crop_with_subject_location',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters',
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('en')),
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('staticpage.html', 'Static page'),
)

CMS_PERMISSION = True

CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'carousel': {
        'plugins': ['CMSCarouselPlugin']
    },
    'info section - image cycle': {
        'plugins': ['ImageCyclePlugin']
    }
}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'project.db',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    'toolbar': 'Basic',
    'extraPlugins': 'filerimage',
    'removePlugins': 'image,flash',
}
```

However, it works fine through the main Admin area, and adding "New FAQ category" through the wizard also works fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is I need to be using djangocms-text-ckeditor>=2.8.1 for my version of Django==3.2.0.

Thank you @mkoistinen!

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the `save()` method for the `CMSWizard`s of both Aldryn FAQ (which works for you) and Aldryn NewsBlog (which does not) there is a clue that perhaps you have set the settings `WIZARD_CONTENT_PLUGIN` and `WIZARD_CONTENT_PLUGIN_BODY`? FAQ uses these settings whereas NewsBlog does not, instead it requires the used of `djangocms-text-ckeditor`'s `TextPlugin`.

I do see that you have `djangocms-text-ckeditor` installed though. I wonder if you haven't yet run migrations for it yet, perhaps?

Are you able to use a normal `TextPlugin` elsewhere in your project?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't have WIZARD_CONTENT_PLUGIN or WIZARD_CONTENT_PLUGIN_BODY set. However, normal TextPlugin doesn't seem to be working correctly - it doesn't crash, but doesn't save the text I add either, comes up as Text <Empty>. When I try `python manage.py makemigrations djangocms-text-ckeditor`, I get an error `App 'djangocms-text-ckeditor' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?`, which it is. Would it be useful if I added my settings.py here?

Comment: OK, I suspect if you can sort the issue with text-ckeditor, you'll solve the Wizard issue =)

Comment: I'm not sure where to even start solving the issue with text-ckeditor :) I attached my settings.py to the question, maybe you can have a look and see if something is missing there?

Comment: Can you try after removing: djangocms_ckeditor_filer? I'm not familiar with that package it it would be good to remove it from the equation for now.

Comment: Just tried it: commented out djangocms_ckeditor_filer from settings.py, and behaviour is still the same :( BTW, what this package does is allows me to upload images into the text editor, and I wonder why is it not default behaviour?

Comment: Which version of djangocms-text-ckeditor are you using?

Comment: You need to be using djangocms-text-ckeditor>=2.8.1 for your version of Django.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106348/discussion-between-dmk12-and-mkoistinen).

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help! I upgraded to djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.9.0 and the TextPlugin is working again, and it solved the issue of creating new content.